# Topology induced by the completion of a topological group

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian topological group and let $\hat{G}$ be its completion, i.e. the group containing the equivalence classes of all Cauchy sequences of $G$. What exactly is the topology of $\hat{G}$?

Comment: For each neighborhood $N$ of zero in $G$, define a neighborhood $\hat{N}$ in $\hat{G}$ consisting of those equivalence classes for which all sequences in the class are eventually in $N$.  This is a base (of neighborhoods of zero) for the new topology.

Comment: Another remark.  Unless $G$ is metrizable, you cannot expect the "completion" by sequences to be complete in the sense of uniform space.  So normally we would do completion by nets or by filters or similar.

Comment: @GEdgar: How do we know that this $\hat{N}$ will be nonempty?

Comment: It contains many constant sequences.  For general $G$ it could happen that every cauchy sequence is eventually constant, so that the sequential completion is nothing new.

Comment: @GEdgar: I see, thank you.

Comment: @GEdgar: If you would like to post this as answer i will gladly vote and accept it.

Comment: @MSina: Do we really need a [completeness] tag?

Comment: @Manos: Out of curiosity, what equivalence relation are we looking at on $G$? And is $G$ metrizable, or how do you define Cauchy sequences?

Comment: See also [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311897/completion-as-a-functor-between-topological-rings). It's about topological rings, but the answer of Martin Brandenburg also fits to topological groups. I really recommend the book "General Topology" from Nicolas Bourbaki for further details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**formerly a remark**

For each neighborhood $N$ of zero in G, define a neighborhood $\hat{N}$ in $\hat{G}$ consisting of those equivalence classes for which all sequences in the class are eventually in $N$. This is a base (of neighborhoods of zero) for the new topology.

Comment: This construction of $\hat N$ is not well-defined. Consider $G = \mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology, $N = (-1,1)$. Then the Cauchy sequences $(1 - 1/2^n)_n$ and $(1 + (-1/2)^n)_n$ are equivalent, but the first one is an element of $\hat N$ while the second one is not. (Thanks to Tim Baumann for bringing this point to my attention and supplying this counterexample.)

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt... Formulation says "all sequences in the class".  So in this example, the class of $(1-1/2^n)$ is not in $\widehat{N}$.

Comment: Ah, okay! Thanks for the quick reply and sorry that I didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: @GEdgar I just want to know what do you mean by "all sequence in the class eventually in $N$",is it  if $[x_n] \in \hat{N}$ there is an $k$ such that whenever ${y_n} \in [x_n]$, $y_n \in N$ for all $n \geq k$, or for each element in $[x_n]$ $k$ may be different ?

Comment: Are you talking about *open* neighborhoods here ? (If yes, then OK. If no, is it clear that just defining a system of neighborhoods defines a topology?)

Comment: In this context we distinguish neighborhoods with open neighborhoods (for axioms, see 2.1 of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Definition_via_neighbourhoods)).
Though I have not seen why the 4th axiom holds for the given system, nor why the completion is indeed a topological group (i.e. addition is continuous).

Comment: How does a generic open set of $\hat{G}$ look like? Are open sets $\hat{G}$ defined to be of the form $\hat{U}$ for open $U\subset G$? Or rather, we should define them to be of the form $\hat{U}+x$ for all open $U\subset G$ containing $0\in G$ and all $x\in\hat{G}$?

Answer (score 8):

$\def\scrB{\mathscr{B}}
\def\scrP{\mathscr{P}}
\def\scrN{\mathscr{N}}
\def\c{\mathrm{c}}$I will give a more detailed explanation after GEdgar's answer. Most importantly, it is not immediately obvious that the translation invariant family of subsets obtained from GEdgar's answer induces a topology; some work must be done (see Lemma 3 below). (Many thanks to M W and his explanation on his comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4762701/394668).) Additionally, I will provide other insights into $\hat{G}$: Lemma 7 gives an alternative definition for the topology on the completion, and Lemma 9 provides its universal property.

Given a set $X$, denote $\scrP(X)$ to the power set of $X$.

> **Definition 1.** Let $X$ be a set and let $\scrB:X\to\scrP(\scrP(X))$ be a function. We say that $\scrB$ is a *local basis system* if for all $x\in X$ the following holds:
>
> 1. $\scrB(x)\neq\varnothing$,
> 2. For all $B\in\scrB(x)$, $x\in B$,
> 3. For all $B\in\scrB(x)$ and $y\in B$, there is $C\in\scrB(y)$ with $C\subset B$,
> 4. For all $B,C\in\scrB(x)$ there is $D\in\scrB(x)$ such that $D\subset B\cap C$.

It not difficult to prove that 3+4 is equivalent to “for all $B,C\in\scrB(x)$ and $y\in B\cap C$ there is $D\in\scrB(y)$ such that $D\subset B\cap C$.” Every local basis system is a *neighborhood basis system* too (a slightly different notion given by properties $(i)$-$(iv)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1099202/394668)).

Here's an example: if $G$ is some abelian group and $G\supset G_1\supset G_2\supset\cdots$ is a filtration by subgroups, then defining $\scrB:G\to\scrP(\scrP(G))$ by
$$
\scrB(x)=\{x+G_n\mid n\geq 1\},\quad x\in G,
$$
always gives a local basis system on $G$.

Recall that given a topological space $X$, a *local basis at $x\in X$* is a family $\mathcal{B}$ of open neighborhoods of $x$ such that for all open neighborhoods $U\subset X$ of $x$ there is $B\in\mathcal{B}$ with $B\subset U$.

Local basis systems are an alternative way to characterize topologies:

> **Lemma 2.** Let $X$ be a set and $\mathscr{B}:X\to\mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(X))$ be a function. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. The set
>    \begin{equation}\label{eq:top gen SBL}
>     τ_\mathscr{B}=\{U\subset X\mid \forall x\in U,\ \exists B\in\mathscr{B}(x)\text{ with } B\subset U\}
>    \end{equation}
>    is a topology on $X$ and for all $x\in X$, it holds that $\mathscr{B}(x)$ is a local basis at $x\in X$ for $(X,τ_\mathscr{B})$.
> 2. There is a topology on $X$ for which $\mathscr{B}(x)$ is a local basis $x$ for all $x\in X$.
> 3. $\mathscr{B}$ is a local basis system on $X$.
>
> Moreover, if these equivalent conditions hold, then $\tau_\scrB$ is the unique topology on $X$ for which $\scrB(x)$ is a local basis at $x$, for all $x\in X$.

I'll leave the proof to the interested reader (part of it it's done in p.8 [here](https://www.math.tugraz.at/%7Eganster/lv_topologie_ss_2019/04_base_subbase_neighbourhood_base.pdf)).

Now, we come back to our case of interest: Let $G$ be an topological abelian group, and denote $\hat{G}$ to its completion. For simplicity reasons (and because I don't know anything about filters and nets), assume $G$ is *locally countably generated* (also known as first-countable space). Then $\hat{G}$ is the set of Cauchy sequences in $G$ modulo the equivalence relation $(x_n)\sim(y_n)$ if and only if $x_n-y_n\xrightarrow{n\to+\infty}0$ (one checks this is an equivalence relation). Note that given a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $G$, the equivalent Cauchy sequences to $(x_n)$ are exactly those of the form $(x_n+s_n)$, where $s_n\to 0$.
Given an open set $U$ of $G$, we define
$$
\tag{1}\label{subset}
\hat{U}=\{[x_n]\in\hat{G}\mid \text{for all } (y_n)\in[x_n],\text{ we have }y_n\in U\text{ for almost all }n\}
$$
(“Almost all” means “all but a finite set.”) The sum on $\hat{G}$ is defined by $[x_n]+[y_n]=[x_n+y_n]$ (one checks this is well-defined). Now, define $\scrB:\hat{G}\to\scrP(\scrP(\hat{G}))$ to be
$$
\label{neig_sys}\tag{2}
\scrB(x)=\{x+\hat{U}\mid U\subset G\text{ is an open neighborhood of zero}\},
$$
for $x\in\hat{G}$. It is left to prove:

> **Lemma 3.** The function $\scrB$ is a local basis system on $\hat{G}$.

The topology on $\hat{G}$ is then the one obtained from Lemma 2. It readily follows that $\hat{G}$ is first-countable.

*Proof.* Conditions 1 and 2 from Definition 1 are trivial. Let $(U_n)$ be a countable local basis of $G$ at $0$. We can suppose that $(U_n)$ is decreasing.

Given any set $S\subset G$, define $\hat{S}$ as usual ($\hat{S}$ is the set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences such for each member on the class almost all its terms lie on $S$).

$\underline{1^{\mathrm{st}}\text{ step}}\colon$ Let $S\subset G$ be a subset set and let $[x_n]\in \hat{S}$. We claim there is an integer $N$ such that $x_n+U_N\subset S$ for all $n\geq N$. To look for a contradiction, suppose there's no such $N$. Then, for each $N$, there is $s_N\in U_N$ and $n_N\geq N$ such that $x_{n_N}+s_N\not\in S$. But $[(x_{n_N})_N]\in \hat{S}$ (for $[(x_n)_n]\in\hat{S}$ and $n_N\to +\infty$) and $s_N\to 0$, so contradiction. Now we claim that $[x_n]+\hat{U}_N\subset\hat{S}$. Let $[y_n]\in\hat{U}_N$ and $s_n\to 0$. Then $x_n+y_n+s_n\in x_n+U_N\subset S$ for all $n\gg 0$. That is, $[x_n]+[y_n]=[x_n+y_n]\in\hat{S}$.

$\underline{2^{\mathrm{nd}}\text{ step}}\colon$ We show 3+4 of Definition 1 by showing the equivalent condition stated after it. Let $y,z\in \hat{G}$ and let $V,W\subset U$ be open neighborhoods of zero. Let $x\in (y+\hat{V})\cap(z+\hat{W})$ (in particular, $x-y\in\hat{V}$ and $x-z\in\hat{W}$). We claim there is $k$ such that $x+\hat{U}_k\subset (y+\hat{V})\cap(z+\hat{W})$. To look for a contradiction, suppose that for all $k$, we have $x+\hat{U}_k\not\subset (y+\hat{V})\cap(z+\hat{W})$. Then at least one of the sets
\begin{align*}
 \{k&\mid x+\hat{U}_k\not\subset y+\hat{V}\}\\
 \{k&\mid x+\hat{U}_k\not\subset z+\hat{W}\}
\end{align*}
is infinite. Suppose it's the first one. Then $x-y+\hat{U}_k\not\subset\hat{V}$ for infinitely many $k$. But this is a contradicion since $x-y\in\hat{V}$ and by first step and since $x-y+\hat{U}_{k+1}\subset x-y+\hat{U}_k$. $\square$

---

This finishes the proof that $\hat{G}$ has a well-defined topology (hence, answering OP's question). We will answer a couple extra questions.

We remark that $\hat{G}$, along with this topology, is a topological group (proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4762701/394668)).

After, we note that the map $\phi:G\to\hat{G}$ sending $x\in G$ to the class of the sequence constantly $x$ is continuous: it suffices to verify that $\phi$ is continuous at the identity (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318867/continuous-homorphisms-between-topological-groups)), so we will show that $\phi^{-1}(\hat{U})=U$, where $U\subset G$ is an open neighborhood of zero. The containment $(\subset)$ is easy. For the converse, let $x\in U$ and pick $s_n\to 0$. Then $x+s_n\to x$ (sum is continuous in $G$), whence $x+s_n\in U$ for all $n\gg 0$; thus, $\phi(x)\in\hat{U}$.

*Remark 4.*

1. $\hat{G}$ is always Hausdorff: By Lemma 10.1 of Atiyah, MacDonald, *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*, we have to show that $\bigcap_{\substack{U\subset\hat{G}\text{ open}\\ \text{nbhd of }0}}U
   =\bigcap_{\substack{U\subset G\text{ open}\\ \text{nbhd of }0}}\hat{U}$ equals $\{0\}$. Let $[x_n]\in\bigcap_{\substack{U\subset G\text{ open}\\ \text{nbhd of }0}}\hat{U}$. Then $x_n\in U$ for all $n\gg 0$ and for all $U\subset G$ open neighborhoods of zero. That is, $x_n\to 0$, whence $[x_n]=0$.
2. Denote $\phi:G\to\hat{G}$ to the map that sends $x\in G$ to the class of the sequence constantly $x$. Then $\phi(G)$ is dense in $\hat{G}$: Since $\hat{G}$ is first-countable, it suffices to see that $\phi(G)$ is sequentially dense. Let $x=[x_n]\in\hat{G}$. Then $\phi(x_n)\to x$ in $\hat{G}$ iff $\phi(x_n)-x\to 0$. To prove the latter, let $U\subset G$ be an open neighborhood of zero. To show $\phi(x_n)-x\in \hat{U}$ for all $n\gg 0$, let $s_n\to 0$ and pick $V\subset G$ open neighborhood of zero such that $V+V\subset U$. Then $x_m-x_n+s_n\in V+V\subset U$ for all $n,m\gg 0$.

The topology on $\hat{G}$ here explained coincides with the one from GEdgar's answer:

> **Lemma 5.** For any subset $S\subset G$, we have $\hat{S}=\widehat{S^\circ}$, where $S^\circ$ is the interior of $S$.

*Proof.* On the one hand, it is clear that $\hat{S}\supset\widehat{S^\circ}$, for $\hat{S}\supset\hat{T}$ for all subsets $T\subset S$. To prove the converse, let $U_n\subset G$ be a decreasing countable local basis of $0$ and let $[x_n]\in\hat{S}$. Then there is $N$ such that $x_n+U_N\subset S$ for all $n\geq N$ (this is the first step of last proof). In other words, $x_n+U_N\subset S^\circ$ for all $n\geq N$. Let $s_n\to 0$. Then $s_n\in U_N$ for all $n\gg 0$, whence $x_n+s_n\in x_n+U_N\subset S^\circ$ for all $n\gg 0$. That is, $[x_n]\in\widehat{S^\circ}$. $\square$

*Exercise 6.* Let $x_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $G$. Let $k_n$ be natural numbers such that $\lim_n k_n=+\infty$. Then $(x_{k_n})_n$ is Cauchy and $[x_n]=[x_{k_n}]$ in $\hat{G}$.

The following gives an alternative way to define the topology on $\hat{G}$.

> **Lemma 7.** For the topology on $\hat{G}$ (induced by Lemmas 2 and 3) the set $\mathcal{B}=\{\hat{V}\mid V\subset G\text{ open}\}$ is a basis.

*Proof.* Note that $\mathcal{B}$ is an abstract basis, for $\bigcap_{i=1}^n\hat{V}_i=\widehat{\bigcap_{i=1}^nV_i}$.

Let $V\subset G$ be open. Let $x\in\hat{V}$. As explained in the proof of Lemma 3, first step, there is an open neighborhood of zero $U\subset G$ with $x+\hat{U}\subset\hat{V}$.

Conversely, let $[x_n]\in\hat{G}$, suppose that $W\subset G$ is an open neighborhood of zero and pick $[y_n]\in [x_n]+\hat{W}$. We have to find an open $V\subset G$ with $[y_n]\in\hat{V}\subset [x_n]+\hat{W}$. Equivalently, such that
$$
\tag{3}\label{eq}
[y_n]-[x_n]\in\hat{V}-[x_n]\subset\hat{W}.
$$

As usual, suppose $(U_n)$ is a countable and decreasing local basis at $0\in G$.

$\underline{\text{Claim i}}\colon$ *For each $K$ there is $M(K)$ such that $[y_n]\in\widehat{y_m+U_K}$ for all $m\geq M(K)$*: Pick $K'$ such that $U_{K'}+U_{K'}\subset U_K$ (existence of such $K'$ can be deduced from the continuity of the sum in $G$). Pick an $M$ such that $y_n-y_m\in U_{K'}$ for all $n,m\geq M$. Pick $s_n\to 0$. Then, for $m\geq M$,
$$
y_n-y_m+s_n\in U_{K'}+U_{K'}\subset U_K,\quad \forall n\gg 0,
$$
i.e., $y_n+s_n\in y_m+U_K$ for all $n$ big enough and $m\geq M$. Hence, $[y_n]\in\widehat{y_m+U_K}$.

$\underline{\text{Claim ii}}\colon$ *There is $N$ such that $y_m+U_K-x_n\subset W$ for all $n,m,K\geq N$*. Suppose not. Then, for each $N$, there are $n_N,m_N,K_N$ and $s_N\in U_{K_N}$ such that $\lim_N\min(n_N,m_N,K_N)=+\infty$ and $y_{m_N}-x_{n_N}+s_N\not\in W$. Since $s_{N}\xrightarrow{} 0$ and by exercise 6 we have $[(y_{m_N}-x_{n_N})_N]=[(y_{m_N})_N]-[(x_{n_N})_N]=[(y_m)_n]-[(x_n)_n]\in\hat{W}$, we arrive a contradiction.

$\underline{\text{Claim iii}}\colon$ *There is $N$ such that $\widehat{y_m+U_K}-[x_n]\subset\hat{W}$ for all $m,K\geq N$.* Pick the $N$ of claim ii. Let $m\geq N$ and pick $[z_n]\in\widehat{y_m+U_K}$. Let $s_n\to 0$. Then
$z_n+s_n-x_n\in y_m+U_K-x_n\subset W$, for all $n\gg 0$, by claim ii. In other words, $[z_n]-[x_n]\in\hat{W}$, and we win.

We now can prove \eqref{eq}. Let $N$ be as in claim iii and pick $K\geq N$ and $m\geq\max(K,M(K))$, where $M(K)$ comes from claim i. Then $[y_n]-[x_n]\in\widehat{y_m+U_K}-[x_n]\subset\hat{W}$. $\square$

Next, we will investigate the universal property of $\hat{G}$.

> **Definition 8.** A topological abelian group $G$ is *sequentially complete* if it is Hausdorff and every Cauchy sequence converges. In the case $G$ is first-countable we will simply say that it is *complete* if it is sequentially complete.

Note that the Hausdorff condition provides uniqueness of limit for (Cauchy) sequences. The reason for the terminology is because the term ‘complete’ is reserved for a different notion when the group is not first-countable (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group#Complete_commutative_topological_group) or Bourbaki, *General Topology*, II.3).

The first-countable group $\hat{G}$ is complete: in Remark 4.1 we argue the Hausdorff property and convergence of Cauchy sequences is proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4765155/394668).

> **Lemma 9** (Universal property of the completion of a first-countable abelian topological group). Let $G$ be a first-countable abelian topological group. The map $\phi:G\to\hat{G}$ is universal among morphisms $G\to H$ of topological abelian groups, with $H$ sequentially complete.

To prove the universal property, we'll use a nice topological property that topological groups have.

*Remark 10*. On a topological group $G$, every element $g\in G$ has a neighborhood basis of closed sets: it suffices to show it for $g=e$, the identity element. In turn, it suffices to show that for every neighborhood $U\subset G$ of $e$ there is a neighborhood $V\subset G$ of zero with $\overline{V}\subset U$. But we know that there is a neighborhood $V\subset G$ of $e$ with $VV\subset U$, and by the [closure formula for topological groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2650540/394668), it follows that $\overline{V}\subset VV$.

*Proof.* (Thanks to [Anne Bauval](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4765712/394668) for pointing out the missing ingredient in the proof.) Let $\psi:G\to H$ be such a map. Uniqueness of a factorization $\tilde{\psi}:\hat{G}\to H$ follows from the facts that $\hat{H}$ is Hausdorff, $\phi(G)$ is dense in $\hat{G}$ (Remark 4) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543962/f-g-continuous-from-x-to-y-if-they-are-agree-on-a-dense-set-a-of-x-th). It remains to show existence.

Note that continuity of $\psi$ implies that it sends Cauchy sequences in $G$ to Cauchy sequences in $H$. Hence, we can define a map
\begin{align*}
 \tilde{\psi}:\hat{G}&\to H\\
 [x_n]&\mapsto\lim_n\psi(x_n).
\end{align*}
Note that $(\psi(x_n))$ has a unique limit on $H$, for $H$ is Hausdorff. We leave as an exercise verifying that this definition for $\tilde{\psi}$ is independent of the choice of representative in $[x_n]$. Note that by continuity of $+_H$, the function $\tilde{\psi}$ is additive. It is left to verify continuity. It suffices to show continuity at zero (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318867/continuous-homorphisms-between-topological-groups)). In turn, since $\hat{G}$ is first-countable, it suffices to show sequential continuity at zero. Suppose $x_n\in\hat{G}$ converges to zero, where $x_n=[x_{nm}]$. This means that for every neighborhoood $U\subset G$ of the identity, $x_n\in\hat{U}$ for all $n\gg 0$. In particular, $x_{nm}\in U$ for all $n,m\gg 0$. By Remark 10, it suffices to show that for an closed neighborhood $V\subset H$ of zero we have that for all $n\gg 0$,
$$
V\ni\tilde{\psi}(x_n)=\lim_m\psi(x_{nm}).
$$
We have $x_{nm}\in\psi^{-1}(V)$ for all $n,m\gg 0$, so $\psi(x_{nm})\in V$ for all $n,m\gg 0$. Hence, for all $n\gg 0$, we get $\lim_m\psi(x_{nm})\in\overline{V}=V.$ $\square$

Thus, completion is an endofunctor of the category of first-countable topological abelian groups: to each morphism $f:G\to H$ of this category it assigns the unique morphism $\hat{f}:\hat{G}\to\hat{H}$ that makes the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
G@>f>> H\\
@VVV@VVV\\
\hat{G}@>\smash{\hat{f}}>>\hat{H}
\end{CD}
$$
commute.

#### Addendum

If $G$ is a group topologized by a filtration of subgroups $(G_n)$, there is a slight notational ambiguity when writing $\widehat{G_n}$. Namely, this can be interpreted either as the completion of the topological group $G_n$ or as the subset of $\hat{G}$ given by taking $U=G_n$ in \eqref{subset}. Each of these bears a topological group structure; the former by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4762701/394668) and the latter because any subgroup of a topological group is a topological group with the subspace topology.

Taking $H=G_n$ in the following lemma implies that these two topological groups are the same.

Given a first-countable topological group $G$, for the next lemma, we'll denote $G^\c$ to the completion of $G$ (we reserve $\widehat{(-)}$ for the subset given in \eqref{subset}). Recall that a quotient group of a topological group is a topological group with the quotient topology (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424410/why-is-the-quotient-group-a-topological-group#comment10119010_2424681)).

> **Lemma 11.** Let $G$ be a first-countable topological group, and suppose $H\subset G$ is an open subgroup. Then:
>
> 1. the set $\hat{H}\subset G^\c$ is a subgroup,
> 2. we have a short exact sequence of topological groups
>    $$
>     0\to H^\c\to G^\c\to G/H\to 0,
>     $$
> 3. the image of $H^\c\to G^\c$ equals $\hat{H}$ (defined in \eqref{subset}).
> 4. the morphism $H^\c\to\hat{H}$ is an isomorphism of topological abelian groups.

*Proof.* We leave proof of part 1 as an exercise.

We tweak a little our notation: for each subset $S\subset G$, we still denote $\hat{S}$ to the subset of $\hat{G}$ given by \eqref{subset}; but for a subset $S\subset H$, we will now denote $\widetilde{S}$ to the open subset of $H^\c$ induced by $S$. With these notations, we claim that for $U\subset H$ open,

\begin{gather}\tag{4}\label{open}
\widetilde{U}=(i^\c)^{-1}(\hat{U})\\
i^\c(\widetilde{U})=\hat{U},
\end{gather}

where $i^\c:H^\c\to G^\c$ comes from $i:G\to H$. These equalities are not difficult to prove and we leave them as an exercise. Part 3 follows from the second equality applied to $U=H$.

Part 2: On the one hand, we note that $G/H$ is discrete (so is the quotient of a topological group by an open subgroup). In particular, $G/H$ is complete. We apply the completion functor to the short exact sequence $0\to G\to H\to G/H\to 0$ to obtain a sequence $0\to H^\c\to G^\c\to G/H\to 0$ of topological abelian groups. Here, the map $G^\c \to G/H$ sends $[x_n]\in G^\c$ to $x_N+H$, for some sufficiently big $N$ (note that $x_n-x_m\in H$ for all $n,m\gg 0$). Suppose $[h_n]\in H^\c$ maps to zero in $G^\c$. By the first equality in \eqref{open}, we have that $[h_n]$ lies in all open neighborhoods $\subset H^\c$ of zero. Since $\hat{H}$ is Hausdorff, this implies $[h_n]=0$ in $H^\c$. On the other hand, $G^\c\to G/H$ is onto for $G\to G^\c\to G/H$ is onto and the composite $H^\c\to G^\c\to G/H$ vanishes. Conversely, suppose $[x_n]\in G^\c$ maps to zero in $G/H$. This means that there is $n_0$ with $x_n\in H$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Hence $[(x_n)_{n\geq n_0}]\in H^\c$ is a preimage.

Part 4: $H^\c\to \hat{H}$ is an isomorphism for it is a continuous bijection and the inverse is also continuous (use the second equality of \eqref{open} plus either Lemma 7 or the fact that an additive map between topological groups is continuous iff it is continuous at zero). $\square$

Comment: For your first step, it’s a little more subtle and I think you need a diagonalization argument.  If you suppose there’s no such $N$, then the contradiction for each $n$ may not occur in the $n$th index.

Comment: @MW Thanks! I just edited it and corrected it.

Comment: For those interested on the well-definedness of the completion of a ring and of a module—and the universal property they satisfy—, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4768444/394668).