# Universal property of the completion of a first-countable abelian topological group

Tags: continuity, commutative-algebra, topological-groups, universal-property, formal-completions

Let $G$ be a first-countable abelian topological group. Its completion $\hat{G}$, set-theoretically, is the family of Cauchy sequences in $G$ modulo the equivalence relation $(x_n)\sim (y_n)$ iff $x_n-y_n\to 0$. It comes equipped with a topology that turns it into a topological abelian group (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4762517/sum-of-the-completion-of-a-topological-abelian-group-is-continuous/4762701#4762701)) plus a natural map $\phi:G\to\hat{G}$ that is a continuous abelian group homomorphism (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4764540/394668)). Moreover, $\hat{G}$ is Hausdorff (see Remark 4.2 from last link) and every Cauchy sequence in $\hat{G}$ converges (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4765155/394668)).

Now I'm wondering about the universal property of $\phi:G\to\hat{G}$.

Let us call a topological abelian group “complete” if it is Hausdorff and every Cauchy sequence converges. (One can show that a *first-countable* topological abelian group is complete iff the canonical morphism into its completion is an isomorphism; see Proposition 7 [here](http://www.niser.ac.in/%7Echitrabhanu/CA/Completion.pdf).)

I know $\phi$ is universal among continuous abelian group homomorphisms of $G$ into *first-countable* complete topological abelian groups: the proof I know is by leveraging Corollary 8, part 2, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4764540/394668).

My question is:

> Is $\phi$ universal among topological abelian group morphisms from $G$ into *all* complete topological abelian groups?

I get stuck at proving continuity of the factorization: Suppose $\psi:G\to H$ is a morphism of abelian topological groups and that $H$ is complete. Given a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$, by continuity, $(\psi(x_n))$ is Cauchy in $H$. Hence we can define \begin{align*}
\hat{\psi}:\hat{G}&\to H\\
[x_n]&\mapsto\lim_n\psi(x_n)
\end{align*}
Note that $(\psi(x_n))$ has a unique limit on $H$ for $H$ is Hausdorff. It is not difficult to show that this definition for $\hat{\psi}$ is independent of the choice of representative in $[x_n]$. Note that by continuity of $+_H$, the function $\hat{\psi}$ is additive.

This is my approach to proving continuity of $\hat{\psi}$: recall that it suffices to show continuity at zero (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1318867/394668)). In turn, since $\hat{G}$ is first-countable, it suffices to show sequential continuity at zero. Suppose $x_n\in\hat{G}$ converges to zero, where $x_n=[x_{nm}]$. This means that for every neighborhoood $U\subset G$ of the identity, $x_n\in\hat{U}$ for all $n\gg 0$. That is, $x_{nm}+s_m\in U$ for all $n,m\gg 0$ and all $s_m\in G$ converging to zero. Now, given an open neighborhood $V\subset H$ of zero, we want to show that for all $n\gg 0$,
$$
V\ni\hat{\psi}(x_n)=\lim_m\psi(x_{nm}).
$$

But how one does do this? I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: (Side remark) The [general definition of completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Completeness) (for non-necessarily first countable uniform spaces) is not in terms of sequences but of filters. See Bourbaki, *General Topology*, II.3.

Comment: @AnneBauval Regarding the typo: Thanks. I just corrected it. Regarding Bourbaki: yes, thank you again; I already knew this, but I don't know filter theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W\subset H$ be an open neighborhood of $0$ such that $W+W\subset V,$ and let $U:=\psi^{-1}(W).$

For all $n,m\gg0,$ $x_{nm}\in U,$  i.e. $\psi(x_{nm})\in W.$

Therefore, for all $n\gg0,$ $\lim_m\psi(x_{nm})\in\overline W\subset V.$

Comment: How does the condition $W+W\subset V$ guarantee that $\overline{W}\subset V$?

Comment: Okay, I just found out about the existence of [the formula for the closure in topological groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2650540/394668), which in our case implies $\overline{W}\subset W+W$. Cool! The thing is that I haven't ever studied topological groups; I ignore the basic general facts. (I learnt about the result “a map between topological groups is continuous iff it is continuous at the identity” while redacting the post.)

Comment: Do you have any book/source recommendation for the matter? I just want them to define the completion in CommAlg: I'm reading through the chapter on completions of Atiyah, MacDonald, *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*. (I've seen that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2650540/closure-in-a-topological-group#comment5478037_2650540) they recommend Hewitt & Ross, *Harmonic Analysis*, Vol. I, first 30 pp. or so.)

Comment: Good! Sorry, I have no recommendation. Best wishes.