# Completion of a Topological Group

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

I am currently reading about completions of a topological group from Atiyah, MacDonald- Commutative Algebra.

**Some prerequisites** :- A Cauchy sequence in a topological group $G$ is defined to be a sequence $({x_n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $G$ such that, for any neighborhood $U$ of $0$, there exists an
integer $s(U)$ with the property that
$x_m - x_n \in U $for all $m,n \geq s(U)$.
Two Cauchy sequences are equivalent if $x_m - y_m \to 0$ in $G$. The set of all
equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences is denoted by $\hat{G}$.

The set $\hat{G}$ is naturally a group. The book mentions that there exists a group homomorphism $$\phi:G\to\hat{G} $$ that sends $x\in G$ to the equivalence class of the constant Cauchy sequence $(x)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.
But it also says that this map is continuous without telling what the topology on $\hat{G}$ is.

Can anyone help me understand the topology on $\hat{G}$?

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192808/topology-induced-by-the-completion-of-a-topological-group?rq=1

Comment: @Stefan The user has not provided a reference source for his argument. Do you know of any such source?

Comment: This topic is covered in Bourbaki, General Topology (§3.4), but probably not in a way that is immediately accessible to you.

Comment: My books all give different constructions for the completion. Of course in general it's complicated, as we need to consider Cauchy filters (not just Cauchy sequences) and a group can have two natural uniformities if it's not Abelian (maybe in this book all groups are Abelian, removing that complication?). Engelking has a chapter on uniform spaces, and there are quite a few books that will cover this too.