# on the topology of the topological completion

Tags: topological-groups, formal-completions

Let be $G$ a topological group and take $\bar{G}$ its completion, namely the set of cauchy sequence quotiented by the natural equivalence relation. The completion is a group and so if I want that it is a topological group is sufficent to show open neighborhoods of the origin (I see this group additively written). I would want to know if is right to describe the neighborhood of the origin like the set of the kind

$\{$class of Cauchy sequence such that a representant is ultimately in U$\}$

where $U$ is a generic open neighborhood of the origin in $G$

Comment: What is a Cauchy sequence on a topological group?

Comment: It's a numerable sequence of elements such that given an open neighborhood of 0 exists an  index such that...

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: For a general topological group, sequences are not enough.  You will have to use Cauchy nets or Cauchy filters instead.  If $G$ is metrizable, though, sequences will be  enough.  Another complication: if $G$ is not Abelian, can we talk about left-Cauchy and right-Cauchy sequences?

Comment: Previous question on completion of an abelian topological group: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/192808/442