# Understanding the $\mathfrak{a}$-adic completion of an $A$-module as a functor

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

$\require{AMScd}$

I recently read the chapter 10 on Completions in Atiyah-MacDonald. They describe the $\mathfrak{a}$-adic completion $\hat{M}$ of an $A$-module $M$ as the inverse limit of an inverse system. They make a remark on page 109, that the function $M \mapsto \hat{M}$ is the object function of a funtor which is not neccessarily right exact in general.

**I want to understand the arrow function of this functor and how composition works.**

I'm thinking of an inverse system in the following manner, we start with a category $I$ of ordinals which can be viewed as 
$$
0 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow \cdots
$$
An inverse system associated to the $\mathfrak{a}$-adic completion of $M$ is the functor $M/{\mathfrak{a}^{i}}M: I^{op} \rightarrow A-Mod.$ Whose image can be viewed as
$$
\cdots \rightarrow M/\mathfrak{a}^{2}M \rightarrow M/\mathfrak{a}M \rightarrow 0 
$$
*My guess on the arrow function is the following:*

Given an arrow  $p: M \rightarrow M''$, we can associate the fundamental system of neighborhoods of $M$
$$
M \supseteq  \mathfrak{a}M \supseteq \mathfrak{a}^{2}M \supseteq \cdots
$$
we can associate a similar fundamental system of neighborhoods on $M''$, namely
$$
pM \supseteq  p(\mathfrak{a}M) \supseteq p(\mathfrak{a}^{2}M) \supseteq \cdots
$$
This gives an inverse system $M''/p(\mathfrak{a}^{i}M)$ associated to $M''$  which can be viewed as 
$$
\cdots \rightarrow M''/p(\mathfrak{a}^{2}M) \rightarrow M''/p(\mathfrak{a}M) \rightarrow  0 
$$

This inverse system has an inverse limit $\hat{M''}$.

Skipping some details, this implies a natural transformation $\tau: M/\mathfrak{a}^{i}M \rightarrow M''/p(\mathfrak{a}^{i}M'')$, which is a map of inverse systems. The natural transformation, gives us a map $\hat{p}: \hat{M} \rightarrow \hat{M}''$.

The issue I have with this guess is that it does not seem to be independent of $M$, for example in the event of a sequence of arrows $M' \rightarrow M \rightarrow M''$.  There is the Artin-Rees lemma to consider, but these maps may not be injective. I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting from the wrong side. Let $f\colon M\to N$ be a homomorphism of $A$-modules.

You can compose it with the canonical mapping $j\colon N\to \hat{N}$ and show it's continuous when $M$ is endowed with the $\mathfrak{a}$-adic topology. Indeed, if $U$ is an open neighborhood of $0$ in $\hat{N}$, we have that, for some $n$, $j^{-1}(U)\supseteq\mathfrak{a}^nN$. Then
$$
(j\circ f)^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(j^{-1}(U))\supseteq f^{-1}(\mathfrak{a}^nN)
\supseteq \mathfrak{a}^nM
$$

The universal property of the inverse limit tells you now that you can build a unique (continuous) homomorphism $\hat{f}\colon\hat{M}\to\hat{N}$ such that the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
M @>f>> N \\
@ViVV @VVjV \\
\hat{M} @>\smash{\hat{f}}>> \hat{N}
\end{CD}
$$
is commutative.

This uniqueness is what also shows that $\widehat{f\circ g}=\hat{f}\circ\hat{g}$, if $g\colon L\to M$ is another homomorphism.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. Thanks friend.

Comment: Lemma 11 from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4768444/394668) provides a more general approach.