# Why is the quotient group a topological group?

Tags: topological-groups

I agree with the claim that translation by an element of the quotient group, $T_{[g]}:G/H \longrightarrow G/H$ Is a continuous function from $G/H$ to $G/H$, when $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. However, for $G/H$ to be a topological group with that operation, one needs multiplication to be a continuous function from $G/H \times G/H$ to $G/H$.

Continuity of the multiplication map implies continuity of left and right multiplication maps, but I don't see why continuity of the left and right multiplication maps would imply the continuity of multiplication map $M : G/H \times G/H \longrightarrow G/H$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, prove that the quotient map $q: G \to G/H$ via $q(x)=xH$ is an open map.  I'm assuming you've already done this since you believe (rightly so) that $T_{[g]}$ is continuous. If not, take a moment to prove this via a homogeneity/translation argument. (By the way, $q$ is open even when $H$ isn't normal.)

Next, prove that $Q(x,y) = (xH, yH)$ defines an open continuous map $Q: G \times G \to G/H \times G/H$.  This isn't hard, because $Q(U \times V) = q(U) \times q(V)$.  Finally, write out the square diagram that says
$$
q \circ \mu = M \circ Q
$$
where $\mu: G \times G \to G$ is your original product.  Check that this square commutes and use open-ness of $Q$ to prove that $M$ is continuous.

A similar trick shows that inversion on $G/H$ is continuous.  Here, $q \circ i = I \circ q$ where $i$ is inversion on $G$ and $I$ is inversion on $G/H$.

Comment: Munkres' text on topology mentions that a topological group is also a topological space that satisfies the $T_1$ axiom. Do we need to show that $G/H$ satisfies the $T_1$ axiom?

Comment: In topological groups $T_1$ implies higher separation axioms, so this is probably sufficient to get the quotient to be $T_1$ too.  My memory isn’t 100%.

Comment: I am not able to prove that the Q function is open. Could you give some more guidance?

Comment: It follows from the fact that $q$ is open.  Can you prove that?

Comment: Is this still true if $H$ is just a closed subgroup?

Comment: Do you mean if $H$ is just closed and not normal?  If it's not normal, how can $G/H$ even be a group? @Cedric

Comment: Synthetically: one uses the universal property of a quotient map—an onto and strongly continuous map (where a *strongly continuous* map $f:X\to Y$ satisfies that $V\subset Y$ is open iff $f^{-1}(V)$ is open)—to show that $(-)^{-1}:G\to G$ descends uniquely to a continuous map $(-)^{-1}:G/H\to G/H$. On the other hand, $Q$ is a quotient map, for it is onto and it was shown to be open; hence, again one uses the universal property to conclude that $\cdot:G\times G\to G$ descends uniquely to a continuous map $\cdot:G/H\times G/H\to G/H$.