# Is the symmetry group of a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ closed?

Tags: lie-groups, group-actions, topological-groups, symmetry, isometry

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $G(K) = \{f \in \mathrm{Isom}~\mathbb{R}^n | f(K) = K\}$, $E=$ be the identity connected component of $G(K)$

1. Is it true that $G(K)$ is a closed subgroup $\mathrm{Isom} ~\mathbb{R}^n$?
2. Is it true that if $G$ is a closed subgroup $\mathrm{Isom} ~\mathbb{R}^n$, then $G/E$ is a discrete group?
3. Is it true that for the exponentiation operation $\mathbb{Z} \times E \to E$ there is a natural continuation to the continuous operation $\mathbb{R} \times E \to E$ ? It seems to me that this implies that $E$ is isomorphic (as topological group) $SO(k)$, am I right?
4. Please advise the best standard textbooks on topological groups / actions of topological groups on topological spaces. My knowledge of this is limited to the corresponding chapter in the book [Elementary Topology](http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/%7Eolegviro/topoman/e-unstable.pdf). As far as I can tell [Topological Groups and Related Structures](https://link.springer.com/book/10.2991/978-94-91216-35-0) not very relevant. I thought [Topological Groups](https://ia801602.us.archive.org/27/items/in.ernet.dli.2015.89986/2015.89986.Topological-Groups.pdf) (Pontryagin) was not very good (maybe outdated), but I’ll be glad to hear that I jumped to conclusions.

Comment: What's the exponentiation operation? Simply $(n,f)\mapsto f^n$? Since $\mathbb{Z}\times E$ is a closed subspace of $\mathbb{R}\times E$ then every continous map defined on it can be extended to entire $\mathbb{R}\times E$ (by Tietze). Do you want the extension to have some particular additional properties? What do you mean by "natural"? Also I don't think $E$ is isomorphic to $SO(k)$. The identity component of $\mathrm{Isom} ~\mathbb{R}^n$ is called a special Euclidean group, you may want to google it.

Comment: Yes, by exponentiation I mean this operation. By the word "natural" I just meant the additional condition: $(a^r)^s = a^{r + s}$ for all $a \in E$ and  $r, s \in \mathbb{R}$. Hm, on Wikipedia, the Euclidean group is called Isom $\mathbb{R}^n$ (which consists of two connected components), but in any case, I am familiar with the classical Lie groups.

Answer (score 2):

In general:

> **Lemma 1.** Let $X$ be a topological space and $C\subseteq X$ a connected component. Then $C$ is closed.

*Proof.* [Connected Components are Closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486461/connected-components-are-closed) $\Box$

> **Lemma 2.** Let $G$ be a topological group and $E\subseteq G$ be the identity component of $G$. Then $E$ is a closed normal subgroup of $G$.

*Proof.* Consider multiplication $M:G\times G\to G$, $M(g,h)=gh$ and the inverse map $I:G\to G$, $I(g)=g^{-1}$.

1. By lemma 1 $E$ is closed.
2. Since $E$ is connected then so is $E\times E$. Since $M$ is continuous then $M(E\times E)$ is connected. Since $M(e,e)=e$, $M(E\times E)$ is connected and $E$ is a connected component then $M(E\times E)\subseteq E$. In particular $E$ is closed under multiplication. Analogously $I(E)\subseteq E$. Thus $E$ is a subgroup.
3. For any $h\in G$ consider the inner automorphism $f_h:G\to G$, $f_h(g)=hgh^{-1}$. Obviously $f_h$ is continuous and since $f_h(e)=e$ then analogously to point $2$ we get $f_h(E)\subseteq E$. Since this holds for any $h$ then $E$ is normal. $\Box$

> **Lemma 3.** Let $G$ be a topological group and $E$ be the identity component. Then $G/E$ is totally disconnected.

*Proof.* This follows from the fact that the quotient map $\pi:G\to G/E$ [is open](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424410/why-is-the-quotient-group-a-topological-group#answer-2424681) and the fact that connected components of $G$ are precisely cosets over $E$. I leave details as an exercise. $\Box$

> 1. Is it true that $G(K)$ is a closed subgroup $\mathrm{Isom} ~\mathbb{R}^n$?

Yes. Assume that $f\in\overline{G(K)}$ in $\mathrm{Isom} ~\mathbb{R}^n$. So there is a net $(f_\alpha) \in G(K)$ convergent to $f$. In particular for each $x\in K$ we have that $f_\alpha(x)\in K$ is a convergent net. Thus $f(x)=\lim f_\alpha(x)\in K$, and so $f\in G(K)$. $\Box$

> 2. Is it true that if $G$ is a closed subgroup $\mathrm{Isom}~\mathbb{R}^n$, then $G/E$ is a discrete group?

By lemma 3 $G/E$ is always totally disconnected. Generally $G/H$ is discrete if and only if $H$ is an open subgroup of $G$.

Now in this particular case, our $E$ has to be contained in $G$ for $G/E$ to even make sense. Or maybe you meant $G/(G\cap E)$? Either way note that $\mathrm{Isom} ~\mathbb{R}^n$ is not connected, but its identity component is so called [special Euclidean group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group) $E^+(n)$ which is of index $2$. It can be shown that a closed subgroup of finite index has to be open. And thus $\mathrm{Isom} ~\mathbb{R}^n/E^+(n)$ is discrete (with two elements). And also every quotient $G/(G\cap E)$ has to be discrete, because $G\cap E$ is always open in $G$.

Another way to look at this is from Lie perspective (since $\mathrm{Isom} ~\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Lie group). A Lie group is a manifold, and connected components of manifolds (or any locally connected space) are open. Also since a closed subgroup of a Lie group is Lie as well, then this generalizes to any closed subgroup $G$ of $\mathrm{Isom} ~\mathbb{R}^n$ and its own identity component.

> 3. Is it true that for the exponentiation operation $\mathbb{Z} \times E \to E$ there is a natural continuation to the continuous operation $\mathbb{R} \times E \to E$ ?

I assume that by exponentiation you mean $(n,f)\mapsto f^n$ map. Assume it is a group action, i.e. $(f^n)^m=f^{n+m}$. Then $x^2=x^{1+1}=(x^1)^1=x$. In particular $x$ is the identity element. And thus our function is a group action only when $E$ is trivial.

So the question is whether this exponentiation map can be extended to full $\mathbb{R}$? Obviously by Tietze any continuous function $\mathbb{Z}\times E\to E$ can be extended to $\mathbb{R}\times E\to E$. But if we want the additional "being a group action" property, then $E$ has to be trivial, and thus $\mathbb{R}$ can trivially act on it. That's the only case where it works.

> It seems to me that this implies that $E$ is isomorphic (as topological group) $SO(k)$, am I right?

This depends on $K$. Consider $K=[0,1]\cup\{2\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Then the only isometry $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that maps $K$ to $K$ is the identity. Meaning both $G(K)$ and its identity component are trivial groups.

On the other hand the $\mathrm{Isom} ~\mathbb{R}^n$ group (without restrictions) has the special Euclidean group as the identity component. This group is isomorphic to a semidirect product of $SO(n)$ by $T(n)$ (the subgroup of all translations). So again not $SO(n)$. I'm not sure if there is $K$ such that the identity component of $G(K)$ is $SO(n)$ to be honest.

Comment: "Algebraically? Topologically?"
In the category of topological groups (that is, there is one bijection that is both group isomorphisms and homeomorphisms). The remark "(as topological group)" indicated this.

Comment: @AivazianArshak fair enough. I've updated the answer. Still, I don't know the precise answer to that question.

Comment: If $E$ is not abelian, then exponentiation is not an action of the group $\mathbb{Z}$ on $E$. The only thing that needs to be preserved is the property of multiplication of powers (see my last comment under the question)

Comment: @AivazianArshak the $(a^r)^s=a^{r+s}$ rule you want is not even true for $\mathbb{Z}$, isn't it? E.g. consider $K=S^1$ and any rotation. A valid rule is $a^{r+s}=a^ra^s$.

Comment: If $(ab)^n = a^n b^n$ then $abab = aa bb$. So $ab = ba$. Hence each group is abelian.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a typo there, of course there must be $rs$.

Comment: @AivazianArshak unfortunately I have to leave now, and I see that I didn't consider $K$ in my answer (which is very wrong on my side). I will leave the answer for now and get back to it in few hours to fix it (hopefuly).

Comment: Oh, you probably mean only that this is always the action of the group $\mathbb{Z}$ on the set $E$, and I thought about the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on the group $E$ (which is not the case). Sorry for this confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @AivazianArshak actually, after further analysis I think that exponentiation is never a group action, except for trivial case. See the updated answer. I will analyze the problem with $K$ later.

Comment: Ah, yes, this is the action of the monoid $(\mathbb{Z}, *)$ on the set $E$. If $E$ is abelian, then this is the action of the monoid $(\mathbb{Z}, *)$ on the group $E$ (abelian groups = $\mathbb{Z}$-modules).