# If $M$ is a finitely generated module over a Noetherian ring $A,$ then $\widehat{\mathfrak{a}M}=\hat{\mathfrak{a}} \hat{M}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a Noetherian ring $A$. Let $\mathfrak{a}\subset A$ be an ideal and denote $\hat{M}$ to the $\mathfrak{a}$-adic completion of $M$. Then how can I show that $\widehat{\mathfrak{a}M}=\hat{\mathfrak{a}} \hat{M}$?

I know that $\hat{A}$ is a flat $A$-module. I need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand\ideal{\mathfrak}$The completion of a finitely generated module $M$ over a Noetherian ring $A$ can be obtained by extension of scalars: $\hat M\cong\hat A\otimes_AM$.
By associativity of tensor product:
\begin{align}
\hat{\ideal a}\otimes_{\hat A}\hat M
&\cong(\hat A\otimes_A\ideal a)\otimes_{\hat A}(\hat A\otimes_AM)\\
&\cong((\hat A\otimes_A\ideal a)\otimes_{\hat A}\hat A)\otimes_AM\\
&\cong(\hat A\otimes_A\ideal a)\otimes_AM\\
&\cong\hat A\otimes_A(\ideal a\otimes_AM)
\end{align}
From the canonical epimorphism $\ideal a\otimes_AM\twoheadrightarrow\ideal aM$, we get the commutative diagram below, where the top row is surjective:$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\hat A\otimes_A(\ideal a\otimes_AM)@>>>\hat A\otimes_A(\ideal aM)\\
@V\sim VV@VV\sim V\\
\hat{\ideal a}\otimes_{\hat A}\hat M@>>>\widehat{\ideal aM}
\end{CD}
Consequently, the bottom row is surjective as well, but since its image is $\hat{\ideal a}\hat M$, this concludes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\a{\mathfrak{a}}$There's no need for Noetherianity assumptions. The result is still true for an arbitrary ring $A$ and an arbitrary $A$-module $M$, *as long as $\mathfrak{a}$ is a finitely generated ideal*. Indeed, one has inclusions of $\hat{A}$-submodules of $\hat{M}$
$$
\a\hat{M}\subset\hat{\a}\hat{M}\subset\widehat{\a M},
$$
so it suffices to see that the left module equals the right one. Let $f_1,\dots,f_r\in A$ be generators of $\a$. We have a surjection $A^{\oplus r}\xrightarrow{(f_1,\dots,f_r)}\a M$. By [0315](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0315) (2), we have a surjection $\smash{\hat{A}}^{\oplus r}\xrightarrow{(f_1,\dots,f_r)}\widehat{\a M}$. But the image of $\smash{\hat{A}}^{\oplus r}\xrightarrow{(f_1,\dots,f_r)}\hat{M}$ is $\a \hat{M}$.

Comment: This argument is taken from [05GG](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05GG).