# Is $\widehat{IM}=\widehat I \widehat M$ for any finitely generated module $M$, where $\widehat {(-)}$ denotes completion w.r.t. maximal ideal?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian, local-rings, formal-completions

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring, and let $(\widehat R, \widehat{\mathfrak m})$ be its $\mathfrak m$-adic completion. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module.

Then, is it true that $\widehat{IM}=\widehat I \widehat M? $

I know this is true if $I=\mathfrak m$ as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136113), but I'm not sure what happens for general $I$. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. As far as I can see, the same proof as in the linked post works with $\mathfrak{a}$ replaced by $I$.

One thing to keep is mind is that $I$ is also finitely generated $R$-module so $\hat{I}\simeq I\otimes_{A}\hat{A}$ where the completions are $\mathfrak{m}$-adic.

Comment: And the proof works for $A$ Noetherian, not necessarily local and completed at some ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ (not necessarily maximal).

Comment: An interesting particular case is $M=I$, i.e., in $\mathfrak{a}$-adic completions, one has the equality $\widehat{I^n}=\hat{I}^n$ of ideals of $\hat{A}$.