# Counterexample to $\hat{\mathfrak{a}}\hat{M}=\widehat{\mathfrak{a}M}$ when the base ring is not Noetherian or the module $M$ is not finitely-generated

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, examples-counterexamples, formal-completions

$\def\fra{\mathfrak{a}}$[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3136261/394668) it is proven that for $A$ a Noetherian ring, $\fra\subset A$ an ideal and $M$ a finitely-generated $A$-module and if we take $\fra$-adic completions, then $\hat{\mathfrak{a}}\hat{M}=\widehat{\mathfrak{a}M}$.

In general, it is always true that $\hat{\mathfrak{a}}\hat{M}\subset\widehat{\mathfrak{a}M}$. I was wondering:

> What's an example of a module $M$ for which $\hat{\mathfrak{a}}\hat{M}\not=\widehat{\mathfrak{a}M}$?

The instances I know in the literature that try to exemplify related behaviors in the non-Noetherian case ([here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05JA) and Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, Ch. III, Exercise 2.12, p. 235) are all done for $M=A$; and the thing is that on this case we always have $\hat{\mathfrak{a}}\hat{M}=\widehat{\mathfrak{a}M}$. So what does a counterexample look like?